# Putting Yeast in a Tea Bag

Tags: beer, fermentation, cider, wine, brewing

When making apple cider, beer or white wine, in order to more easily clear up the liquid, can we put our yeast in a tea bag or a piece of cloth so that the alcohol would be produced inside of it and then released into the liquid with causing minimum cloudiness and sediments?

Comment: I don't know but I think that if you isolate the yeast from the wort via the tea bag cloth, it won't be able to reach most of the sugar in the wort.

Comment: I thought this question was a bit silly, but I stand corrected based on the membrane answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will not work with a tea-bag or any other kind of cloth. Unless it's enclosed in a very fine membrane the yeast would easily be able to get through, then disperse and propogate in the main liquid.

**However**, something like this can actually be done. [Some homebrewers](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/f163/yeast-immobilization-magic-beans-fermentation-404698/) have taken a [high-technology cue from industrial beer](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15932239) and do what's known as an *immobilized yeast* fermentation, where the yeast cells are trapped in an inert membrane, allowed to ferment wort, then are left behind when the beer is transferred away.

So this offers almost exactly what you're looking for (yeast entrapped in a meduim so that they can still ferment and be fairly easy to remove after fermentation).

Comment: I watched some videos on youtube about the immobilized yeast and I have one question, do I have to make my immobilized yeast out of free yeast or do I have to purchase them? Anyways, is it possible to make them out of free yeast at all?

Comment: You can make it from whatever yeast you have/want. I doubt whether or not you paid for it will matter.

Comment: "I doubt whether or not you paid for it will matter." By free yeast I meant a kidda yeast that is not Immobilized :D

Comment: Ha, ok I see what you mean. I've never done this before, but there's no reason you can't use any yeast you have (fresh liquid yeast, rehydrated dry yeast, yeast saved from a previous fermentation, whatever).